# What is a correct way to insert into a map of map of list

Tags: c++, stl

I am creating an Indexer Application in C++.
Each unique word in the text files of a directory, I want to store like-
first_map<"word", second_map<"File Object reference", List{line numbers}>

To fill this map first time, I am parsing each file word by word in the directory. To push the data into map, I am getting a compilation error while using like-

```
pool[token][it].push_back(count);
```

I think this would not throw an error if inner map value is of type int.
I also try to use like-

```
pool[token].insert(std::make_pair(it, count);
```

This is also failed with an error.
What is the correct way to insert data into this container?

Complete source is given below-

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>
#include<ctime>

class File {
  public:
    std::string file_name;
    int timestamp;
    File(std::string name) : file_name(name) {
      struct stat st;
      int ierr = stat (file_name.c_str(), &st);
      if (ierr != 0) {
        std::cout << "error in getting timestamp";
      }
      timestamp = st.st_mtime;
    }
};

class Location {
  public:
    std::vector<File> indexer;
    virtual std::map<File*, std::list<int> > find_pattern(std::string& word);
    Location(const char* in_dir){
      DIR* FD;
      struct dirent* in_file;
      /* Scanning the in directory */
      if (NULL == (FD = opendir (in_dir)))
      {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error : Failed to open input directory - %s\n", strerror(errno));
        throw -1;
      }
      while ((in_file = readdir(FD)))
      {
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, "."))
          continue;
        if (!strcmp (in_file->d_name, ".."))
          continue;
        indexer.push_back(File(in_file->d_name));

      }
    }
};
class TextFileLocation : public Location {
  public:
    std::map<std::string, std::map<File*, std::list<int> > > pool;
    TextFileLocation(const char* in_dir) : Location(in_dir){

      for(auto it = indexer.begin(); it != indexer.end(); it++){
        std::ifstream file1(it->file_name);
        if(!file1)
        {
          std::cout<<"Error opening output file"<<std::endl;
          continue;
        }
        std::string line;
        std::string token;
        int count = 0;
        while (std::getline(file1, line))
        {
          count++;
          std::map<File*, std::list<int> > *file_line =
          std::istringstream ss(line);
            while(std::getline(ss, token, ' ')) {
              if(token.empty())
                continue;
              pool[token][it].push_back(count);
            }
        }
      }
    }
    std::map<File*, std::list<int> > find_pattern(std::string& word){
      return pool[word];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The good news:

To make the compiler go away on the line in question:

```
pool[token][&*it].push_back(count);
```

`it` is a `std::vector<File>::iterator`, and `pool` is a

```
std::map<std::string, std::map<File*, std::list<int> > >
```

So, to get a plain `File *` from an iterator, "&*" is the typical approach.

The bad news:

This is not going to work. As soon as `std::vector<File>` reallocates, all native pointers and iterators to its contents get invalidated. Your `std::map` will be left with pointers to never-never land.

And if the object, that this structure is part of, is copied or moved, everything gets nuked from high orbit also.

You will need to completely rethink the overall design of your data, and containers.

Comment: Thanks, I will relook on containers design. Any suggestion your side to make an efficient container with less redundancy of data.

Comment: I recently had to make a hash table with a vector of lists of pairs. It worked out quite nicely. Would this help you?